# Next article section not working in craftcms anyone know what went wrong here?

Tags: php, html, yii, craftcms

one of my craft cms projects, I have articles and once click articles I can read those articles, and in that right side content I have a tab call Next article, but when clicking that nothing response
here the live site - http://ambitmagazine.co.uk/poems/ambit-poetry-competition-2018

screenshot - https://prntscr.com/o9gkph

_entry.html

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}

{% set issue = entry.issue.first() %}
{% set nextArticle = craft.entries.section('articles').after(entry.postDate).order('postDate asc').limit(1).find() %}

<div class="article section{% if entry.largeText %} article--larger-text{% endif %}">
    <div class="article__inner section__inner">

        {% include 'articles/_partials/article-header' with { article: entry, issue: issue } only %}
        {% include "articles/_types/" ~ entry.type %}
        {% if entry.relatedAuthor|length > 0 %}
            {% include 'articles/_partials/article-footer' with { article: entry } only %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if nextArticle|length > 0 %}
            <div class="next-item">
                <a href="{{nextArticle[0].url}}" class="next-item__inner">
                    <span><strong>Next Artcile</strong></span>
                    <span>\</span>
                    <span>{{nextArticle[0].title}}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="article__sidebar-inner"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="article__sidebar-outer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see that this is still present on the live site. Is there anything else you can let us know about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`.after` is doing a >= operation so the current article is included in the results, and is almost certainly going to be the first option.

Doing something like `.after(entry.postDate|date_modify('+1 second'))` will exclude the current article and should give you what you are looking for.

It may be more clear for your query to keep the time as is, but explicitly exclude the current entry by id:

```
{% set nextArticle = craft.entries()
        .section('articles')
        .after(entry.postDate)
        .id(['not', entry.id])
        .order('postDate asc')
        .one() %}
```